# How to make check all checkbox from adapter in android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-widget, android-listview

I make multiple check box with

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,data);
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to make check all checkbox from this adapter

Answer (score 0):

Use getListView().setSelection(int position) in a loop for all the positions in the list.

Assuming data is an array

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    getListView().setSelection(i);
}
```

Comment: thanks you for your respon 

i beginner in android 

how can i get all position in getlistview?

can you make example code

Comment: No of positions in a the list is equal to no of elements in the data object.

Comment: i make it but others checkbox can not set true

can you help me